# Build docker image and upload docker image into directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I use this tutorial to create Docker image:

https://medium.com/@javatechie/kubernetes-tutorial-run-deploy-spring-boot-application-in-k8s-cluster-using-yaml-configuration-3b079154d232

The Docker image is created using:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry/springboot-k8s-example$ sudo docker build -t springboot-k8s-example:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  17.77MB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:17
17: Pulling from library/openjdk
38a980f2cc8a: Pull complete
de849f1cfbe6: Pull complete
a7203ca35e75: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:528707081fdb9562eb819128a9f85ae7fe000e2fbaeaf9f87662e7b3f38cb7d8
Status: Downloaded newer image for openjdk:17
 ---> 5e28ba2b4cdb
Step 2/4 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in b5e6d3d848bb
Removing intermediate container b5e6d3d848bb
 ---> ff16dcdc7f93
Step 3/4 : ADD target/springboot-k8s-demo.jar springboot-k8s-demo.jar
 ---> 0d04c64313d6
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/springboot-k8s-demo.jar"]
 ---> Running in 8d20a1a9c2f0
Removing intermediate container 8d20a1a9c2f0
 ---> 6027a59c6259
Successfully built 6027a59c6259
Successfully tagged springboot-k8s-example:1.0
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry/springboot-k8s-example$
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry/springboot-k8s-example$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
springboot-k8s-example   1.0       6027a59c6259   4 minutes ago   489MB
openjdk                  17        5e28ba2b4cdb   4 months ago    471MB
```

How I can create the docker image and upload it into directory?

Comment: Image is already created with the docker build command. Does `upload it into directory` mean to push image to remote repository like dockerhub, OR make it available to minikube from your local registry?

Comment: Do u mean you want to push the image to a registry or something else ?

Comment: I want to push the image into private registry located on remote Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: If you use docker as your privet registry I can help you but if this is not docker I will not be able to test. Basically u need to login to the registry and then push the image

Comment: yes, this is my goal. the image is a docker image.